# Elasticsearch use of terms of repository, cluster, index, type, and bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

This is not a specific coding problem, but I would like to get an understanding of the use of terms in ES. Can someone give me a detailed definition of:

- Repository
- Cluster
- Index (indices)
- Types
- buckets

I've seen them again and again but could never grasp which ones belong to which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository - Assuming you are coming from spring land, is an abstract term used to refer to a data store. A repository can be a database or a file system or an inverted index based system like ES.

Cluster - Collection of elastic search instances running on the same machine or different machines. They are linked together using the cluster name either declared in elasticsearch.yml or -Des.cluster.name

Index - the logical storage structure used by elastic search to refer to stored data

Types - A specific kind of document that is stored in an index

Buckets - Comes into play when you are doing operations like min/max/count/avg etc on the indexed data. Think of buckets as a group of documents that match the query criteria. Buckets can contain nested buckets.

Comment: so let's say I have a query that looks like `GET localhost:9200/layer_1/layer_2/log_number` or `GET localhost:9200/layer_1/layer_2/_search`, which part is which? I know bucket doesn't really associate with this query, what about the rest?

Comment: There's no direct entity in elastic search for repository as its you application layer concern. In this URL localhost:9200 acts as a the "single node cluster", layer_1 is the index and layer_2 is the type within the index